# Django count in model

Tags: python, django

I have a simple model to register if any user like an article in my blog.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    articles = models.ForeignKey(Articles, verbose_name="Article", null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Auteur", null=False)
```

I just record the user ID and the article ID.
This is the model of Articles :

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, verbose_name="Titre")
    text = HTMLField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='media/articles/', validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Image de présentation")
    games = models.ForeignKey(Games, verbose_name="Jeux", blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Auteur")
    is_statut = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Statut")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
```

I wonder how to do to count for each articles how many "likes" are there ?

I would like to return a `list[]` like this `list[(id_article, number_of_like), ]` if possible ?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

Comment: General unrelated note: both models (`Article`, `Game`) and foreign keys (`article`, `game`) are usually singular in Django. As is your `author` foreign key, and Django's own `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues that might work

```
list = [Article.objects.get(id=Article_ID),Like.objects.filter(articles=Article_ID).count()]
```

Comment: You wellcome. I have a blog project, that I'm procrastinating to finish, it has a similar structure to store likes. Good luck!

Comment: aha ^^ Actualy it's not a blog, I'm trying to build a social gaming network in Django. You can take a look : cjaouani.fr:8000 With google translate you should get a translating version of my site :)

Comment: Wow. That sounds awesome! My company blocks the site.... =/ When I get home I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question:

Example of getting how many likes one Article has:

```
 the_article = Articles.objects.all().first()
 how_many_likes = the_article.like_set.count()
```

Second part for "I would like to return a list[] like this list[(id_article, number_of_like), ] if possible ?":

```
 list = []
 all_articles = Articles.objects.all()
 for one_article in all_articles:
     how_many_likes = one_article.like_set.count()
     list.append([one_article.id, how_many_likes])
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you, yeah it's something like this ;)